# How to get Previous URL query String parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the previous page URL query string parameters

```
document.referrer
```

gives the previous URL but not query string parameters. Is there any way to get that in javascript?
the purpose of reading that is I don't have any control on the previous page and I wanted those parameters in the next call.

I am doing an integration where the login page pop-ups of some third party were based on the client id it asks for the permissions to Allow. once user allows that it redirect to the "redirect URL" passed in the parameter with 2 parameters in query string.

Now I don't have any other way to find out which user has given the access. If I can get the client id on my current page I can get to know that this user has granted the login.

If is there any other way to do it please help me. Or let me know if anything else is also required

Comment: Don't you think, this would be a security issue?

Comment: Yes I know my approach is wrong